# navigator.geolocation error on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile, geolocation

This is snippet from a React app.
app: https://perfect-sunset.herokuapp.com/

The geolocation works fine on desktop.
On iPhone and Android it throws the error alert right away. Location services are ON on the phone.

Any help greatly appreciated!
thank you!

```
 componentDidMount() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            let lat = position.coords.latitude
            let lng = position.coords.longitude
            console.log("getCurrentPosition Success " + lat + lng);
            this.setState({
              location: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lng
              }
            })
            ///..does more stuff..///
          },
          (error) => {
            alert('geolocation error');
            this.setState({
              geoLocatorStatus:  'You geolocation is OFF. Please, use ZIP code.'
            })
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error))
          }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: Infinity
          }
        )
}
```

Comment: Your app needs permissions to use location services on ios/android.

Comment: @KoshVery how would I go about requesting permission? navigator.permissions isn't supported in Safari

Comment: when the app loads in a mobile browser it isn't even asking for permission

Comment: Ok so I went to iOS settings, Location was ON, I turned it OFF, then back ON. It works on my phone now.

Comment: On Android the issue still persists, the app isn't asking to allow geolocation usage